# XML schema prefix error

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have tried to create a XML schema from c# classes(with xsd.exe) in which I am using classes from another XMl schema.

Afterwards i am loading the schema in c# and i am filling up some missing properties like shemalocation for the imported shema and the prefixes for the namespaces.

When i am exporting the xml schema again, the prefix for the imported schema types is wrong, allthough it is declared. The prefix is set to "q1:enumeratedValues".

What i am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:spirit="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009" xmlns:myNamespace="file:///c:/Local/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="file:///c:/Local/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009/memoryMap.xsd" namespace="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009" />
  <xs:element name="signals" type="myNamespace:signals" />
  <xs:complexType name="signals">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="myNamespace:vendorExtensionBase">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="signal" type="myNamespace:signalType" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="vendorExtensionBase" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="xsdversion" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="signalType">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="myNamespace:vendorExtensionBase">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="name" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="bitwidth" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="signed" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fractionalBits" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="defaultValue" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="divider" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="q1:enumeratedValues" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="scaling">
            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:anyAttribute />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Why is that wrong? It looks plausible to me. Just to be clear, the prefix isn't relevant - only the namespace it maps to is.

Comment: Can you add a sample XML ?

Comment: Hi, its not wrong but i would expect the type from the imported schema to look like <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="spirit:enumeratedValues" />. Indeed i got more imported schemas and more custom types, it would be good when the prefixes are the same as in the imported schemas... The only prefeix which is working is of my own shema...

Answer (score 1):

**Namespace *prefix* names are insignificant.**  It is only through the binding of a namespace prefix to a namespace value that namespace prefixes derive meaning.

No conformant XML processor will care about the specific namespace prefix names, and neither should you.

Comment: And just to be clear - that binding is local to an element which contains a particular namespace declaration - it's not some kind of "global" binding.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Correct, the scope of a namespace prefix declaration is limited to the element on which it appears and the descendants of that element.